# SQL (analytical) query to retrieve first and second rows for each value of a group by

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a situation that I would like to resolve in SQL using as few inner joins as possible, so I am thinking of using window functions.

I am using Snowflake, but I am happy to see answers in other DB engines as well.

Table sales has sale_id and seller_id, as well as sale_datetime, amount...
Table seller has seller_id

I would like to get the first and second sales for each seller, as columns preferably (so that I can add and subtract eg sum of amounts). If there is only one sale, ideally I would not retrieve it.

I am trying to use something like this:

```sql
select se.seller_id,sa.*, first_value(sale_datetime) over (ORDER BY
sale_datetime ),  LAG(sale_datetime) OVER (ORDER BY sale_datetime)
from seller se inner join sales sa  on sa.seller_id = se.seller_id
order by se.seller_id;
```

But I would need to add a group by, because the window functions need to be applied at the seller level, not to the total of the table. Whether I add it at the end of the query or inside the window, I get an error.

The other way that I have of doing this without windows is with two with...as clauses that retrieve first and second sale for each seller respectively and a join between them, but I am trying to avoid this for performance reasons.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answer was already mostly there. You just need to use the LAG and use [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number.html)/[QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html)

CTE for Data:

```
with sales(sale_id, seller_id, sale_datetime, amount) as (
    select * from values
    (4, 10, '2022-04-24'::date, 100),
    (3, 10, '2022-04-23'::date, 200),
    (2, 10, '2022-04-22'::date, 400),
    (1, 11, '2022-04-22'::date, 300)
)
```

working SQL:

```
select sa.*,
    LAG(sale_datetime) OVER (partition by sa.seller_id ORDER BY sa.sale_datetime) as prior_sale_date,
    LAG(amount) OVER (partition by sa.seller_id ORDER BY sa.sale_datetime) as prior_amount  
FROM sales AS sa  
qualify row_number() over(partition by sa.seller_id order by sale_datetime) = 2
order by sa.seller_id;
```

gives:

| SALE_ID | SELLER_ID | SALE_DATETIME | AMOUNT | PRIOR_SALE_DATE | PRIOR_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 10 | 2022-04-23 | 200 | 2022-04-22 | 400 |

this works because every row get the prior values via the two LAG's, but we only keep the second row.

I Also dropped the `seller se` table because it is add no value to the process, as it's just a filter.., but that can be present via:

more complex data CTE's:

```
    select * from values
    (4, 10, '2022-04-24'::date, 100),
    (3, 10, '2022-04-23'::date, 200),
    (2, 10, '2022-04-22'::date, 400),
    (1, 11, '2022-04-22'::date, 300)
), seller(seller_id) as (
    select * from values (10),(11),(12),(13)
)
```

working SQL with JOIN back in.

```
select sa.*,
    LAG(sale_datetime) OVER (partition by sa.seller_id ORDER BY sa.sale_datetime) as prior_sale_date,
    LAG(amount) OVER (partition by sa.seller_id ORDER BY sa.sale_datetime) as prior_amount  
FROM seller as se
JOIN sales AS sa
    ON se.seller_id = sa.seller_id
qualify row_number() over(partition by sa.seller_id order by sale_datetime) = 2
order by sa.seller_id;
```

gives:

| SALE_ID | SELLER_ID | SALE_DATETIME | AMOUNT | PRIOR_SALE_DATE | PRIOR_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 10 | 2022-04-23 | 200 | 2022-04-22 | 400 |

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working (even without the row number) with my full dataset. Some of the sellers which have many sales don't appear in the final output.

Comment: OK, got it, I wrapped your query in another query that aggregates per seller, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

ROW_NUMBER and [QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html) could be used:

```
select se.seller_id,sa.*
from seller se 
join sales sa  
  on sa.seller_id = se.seller_id
qualify row_number() over(partition by sa.seller_id order by sale_datetime) <= 2
order by se.seller_id;
```